# How to filter on publishing start/end date in sharepoint 2013 REST api?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I have a rest query here:

```
http://mydev/en/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Page Images')/items?$select=ImageLink,EncodedAbsUrl,PublishingStartDate,PublishingExpirationDate&$filter=PublishingStartDate le '2014-10-05T17:19:52.027Z'&$top=1000
```

but this come back with an error:

```
The field 'PublishingStartDate' of type 'PublishingScheduleStartDateFieldType' cannot be used in the query filter expression.
```

Does anyone know why I cannot filter on it?

Thanks